# Discrepancy in bundling project after upgrading node version from v6.10 to v10.x

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, node-modules

I am using `webpack 2` and `awesome-typescript-loader` for bundling my project in `nodejs`.
I have upgraded my node version from node 6.10 to node 10.16.

After bundling , I am getting `Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'config'.`

There is no dependency for config module in my projects `package.json.`

For node version 6.10 , I am not getting this error.

I compared the bundle.js file and found following discrepancies.

for node 10.x:

/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("config");

/***/ })

for node 6.10:

```
  <pre>
    var CONFIG = require("config");
    CONFIG.util.setModuleDefaults("MyModule", {
    &nbsp;&nbsp;templateName: "t-50",
    &nbsp;&nbsp;colorScheme: "green"
    });
```

I see that the code section for config in node 6.10 is commented out. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: did you try to `npm i config` and build again? maybe you installed it but didn't save it package.json. Did you check `node_modules` folder if `config` is there?

Comment: Yes , i have cleaned my npm cache and tried but still the issue persists.

Comment: Please format the code properly. It is hard to make out. I had edited it you changed it once again. And did you npm install? Not npm cache clear

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading to webpack version 4.35.0 and replacing awesome-typescript-loader with ts-loader 6.0.4 both of which are latest version respectively.

Somehow webpack 2 doesn't seem to bundle the files correctly on node version 10.